# Laravel Cities relation foreign key

Tags: php, orm, laravel, relation

Im really new to laravel, and im sure im doing something wrong

I have 2 tables. `Cities` And `users_metadata`

My cities table look like this

```
id | City        |
1  | New York    |
1  | Los Angeles |
```

users metadata

```
user_id | firt name | last name | cities_id |
1       | Jonh      | Doe       |         2 |
```

So my problem is when i create a relation i get New York, becaus the city id is matched with the user id

City model

```
class City extends Eloquent 
{
    public static $table = "cities";

    public function profile()
    {
        return static::has_many('Profile');
    }
}
```

profile model

```
class Profile extends Eloquent 
{
    public static $timestamps = false;

    public static $table = "users_metadata";

    public static $key = "user_id";

    public function city()
    {
        return static::has_one('City');
    }
}
```

error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'profile_id' in 'where clause'

SQL: SELECT * FROM `cities` WHERE `profile_id` = ? LIMIT 1

Bindings: array (
  0 => 1,
)
```

If i dont pass the id to has one i get the following error

Okay i understand this.

So my questions is am i able to pass the foreign key `cities_id` somehow in my relation to match? Or im doing it all wrong? Can someone give me a basic example?

thank you folks

Comment: @w0rldart please give a descriptive reason for your edits when the reason is not obvious - and there's no need for the "Edit" header.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

City model

```
class City extends Eloquent 
{
    public static $table = "cities";
    public function profile()
}
```

Profile model

```
class Profile extends Eloquent 
{
    public static $timestamps = false;
    public static $table = "users_metadata";
    public static $key = "user_id";
    public function city()
    {
        return static::belongs_to('City');
    }
}
```

I ran into the same problem thinking I should use has_one, but I needed to use belongs_to. user1808639's probably didn't work because you still had a 'has_many' in the city model.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Profile extends Eloquent
{
    public function city()
    {
        return $this->belongs_to('City'); // city_id in the table
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a way of detecting foreign keys automatically. So for your database schema... this models should work fine
Try the following

```
user_id | firt name | last name |   city_id | //city not cities
1       | Jonh      | Doe       |         2 |
```

-

```
class Profile extends Eloquent 
{
    public static $timestamps = false;
    public static $table = "users_metadata";

    public function city()
    {
        return $this->has_one('City');
    }
}
```

/

```
class City extends Eloquent 
{
    public static $timestamps = false;

    public function profiles()
    {
        return $this->has_many('Profile');
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but its still the same, i get back the SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'profile_id' in 'where clause', and i still need to pass the id to the cities relation, and still matches the id with user_id instead of id with city_id

SQL: SELECT * FROM `cities` WHERE `profile_id` = ? LIMIT 1

Comment: Just a small typo fix, `profiles()` not `profile()` as it `has_many`. Post your code where you call the models

Comment: I highly recommend you reading http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent, lines as `public static $table = "cities";` is completely useless as Laravel does that automatically. Do you have any other `users` table? if not, set `users_id` in that table to `id` and post the controller where you call the models.... not only the models

Answer (score 0):

The table rows shouldn't contain whitespaces. So rename "firt name" | "last name" in "firstname" | "lastname". The SQL-error shows me that you're calling the model in the reverse way like City::find(1) in this case Laravel expects inside the "Cities" table the foreign key for the profiles that would be usually "profile_id".

I guess you're looking for something like this:

```
$user_id = 1; 
$user = Profile::find($user_id);

echo $user->firstname." ".$user->lastname." lives in ".$user->city->city;
```